# Como alterar estilo em javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Em jquery:

```
<script>
$( "#main article:nth-child(3) .postSnippet" ).css("display", "block");
</script>
```

Como ficaria em JS puro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seletor fica igual, o que muda é a forma de percorrer o(s) elemento(s) e aplicar o estilo desejado. Exemplo:

```
var e = document.querySelectorAll('#main article:nth-child(3) .postSnippet');
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].style['display'] = 'block';
}
```

Entretanto, não seria mais fácil adicionar um estilo no seu CSS para fazer isso? Exemplo:

```
 #main article:nth-child(3) .postSnippet {
     display: block;
 }
```